# Carbon - check hours after midnight

Tags: laravel, time, php-carbon

in a `laravel` app I have a range of times(`start` and `end`), if the end time is after `00:00:00`, then it would be set to the next Day

**edit**

for exemple : 
 start = `22:00:00` and end = `04:00:00` so here end hour is after `00:00:00` so it should be set to the next day

Comment: *"start or end is after midnight"* - But _all_ times are after midnight... What exactly do you mean by that? If you just have times, like `10:00:00` (10 AM), or `13:30:00` (1:30 PM), those are both after midnight... But they are also both before midnight too... Without an associated Date, this doesn't make sense.

Comment: @TimLewis if I have for exemple start = `22:00:00` and end = `04:00:00` so here end date is after `00:00:00` and it should be set to the next day

Comment: Ok, so that makes a little more sense. If you have a range of times, and the end date is after `00:00:00`, then it would be a new Day. Without that context, your question didn't make any logical sense. In that case, you'd need two `DateTime` (or `Carbon`) objects, and if `endDate` is before `startDate`, increment `endDate`'s day to the next day. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75856302/edit) and provide some code. Also, this is why it's important to work with full Date and Time, and not just time 

Comment: @TimLewis Ok thank you, this approach is correct and works correctly

Comment: I suggest not to reinvent the wheel and to take a look at https://github.com/kylekatarnls/business-time

Answer (score 0):

Usually if start time and end time is on the same day, `$startTime` should be less then `$endTime`, right?
If not so, then `$endTime` they must to be happening different days

So you can just write:

```php
$startTime = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('22:00:00');
$endTime = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('04:00:00');

if($startTime->gt($endTime)) {
   // Here you go, add next day or do whatever you want to do      
}
```

> This approach doesn't work and gives you incorrect result if difference between `$startTime` and `$endTime` is more than 24 hours. (For example: `$startTime = '22:00:00'` and `$endTime = '23:00:00'` but `$endTime` is on the next day. In this cas you must have dates present, otherwise you can't determine if thery are hapening on same day or not )

Comment: this solutions doesn't work

Comment: Show us the code you wrote. It should work

Answer (score -1):

Use `$carbon->gt()`.

```php
if ($startDate->gt(Carbon::today()->startOfDay()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: FYI - There needs to be more of an explanation